# How do I understand the "existence and uniqueness of a vector field's integral curves" and how do I connect it to differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing, vectors, vector-fields

I'm working on a differential equations project where I need to use the "Existence and Uniqueness Theorem for a Vector Field's Integral Curves" to prove the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem for 1st order linear differential equations in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. The instructions for this project are very vague and poorly written, and I'm having trouble making sense of the part about integral curves of vector fields. I'll state the vector integral curve theorem here. If anyone can dumb down this theorem for me or give any pointers on where to start, that would be greatly appreciated.

For a vector field $\textbf{v}(x)$ on a subset $U \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$:

Given any point $p \in U$, and any initial "time" $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that there is a unique, continuously differentiable function $\gamma: (t_{0}-\epsilon, t_{0}+\epsilon)\to U$ defined on the interval $(t_{0}-\epsilon, t_{0}+\epsilon)$ around $t_0$ such that:

1. $\gamma'(t)=\textbf{v}(\gamma(t))$
2. $\gamma(t_0)=p$

The way I'm trying to visualize this right now is that I can choose some point in this vector field's domain, then pick some curve passing arbitrarily close to that point. The rate of change of this curve will be equal to the vector field composed with the equation for the curve. Additionally, evaluating the curve at point $t_0$ will be equal to the point $p$ because the curve passes arbitrarily close to $p$ (I think).

If I'm thinking about this right, how do I start connecting it to the existence and uniqueness theorem for 1st order diff eqs?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! <> The project includes the term _linear_; is it possible that the project is simply to show that every first-order linear system, which we might write\begin{align}x'(t)&=a_1(t)x(t)+b_1(t)y(t)+c_1(t),\\ y'(t)&=a_2(t)x(t)+b_2(t)y(t)+c_2(t),\end{align}for suitable coefficients $a_i$, $b_i$, $c_i$, satisfies the hypotheses of Picard-Lindelöf (and maybe perform some subsidiary investigations)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is not a forest-tree problem. You are just using a different language for the same underlying objects and facts, a coordinate centered view vs. the dynamic of geometric objects (here only points and tangents). It might be that the language of (tangential) vector fields and their integral curves has a more natural connection to manifolds.

$$
x'=v(x),~~ v(t_0)=p
$$
with $x$ and $v(x)$ in $\Bbb R^n$ is also a first-order system of differential equations with initial value, short an IVP.

Depending on the properties of $v$, the existence theorem is the theorem of Peano or the Picard-Lindelöf theorem ($v$ being Lipschitz) or its specialized version as Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem ($v$ being continuously differentiable, thus locally Lipschitz).

One can recast every non-autonomous system as autonomous system with the time as additional component of the state. This gives a slight restriction of the general claim of Picard-Lindelöf, as there the ODE function only needs to be continuous in time, while being Lipschitz in the state vector.

Comment: I understand that the Picard-Landelof theorem is fundamentally the same as the Existence and uniqueness theorem for 1st order diff. equations--otherwise this project I'm doing would be pointless. Do you know how one would begin to illustrate that they're the same mathematically?

Comment: Not only fundamentally the same, but just another name for the same thing. The only distinction I can make out is the differences between the theory for autonomous and the slightly more general non-autonomous systems. And also the distinction between a more differential-geometric approach and a (even more slightly) more general dynamical-system approach.